# Custom lexer in Python prompt_toolkit

Tags: python, lexer, prompt-toolkit

While the `prompt_toolkit` documentation indicates that "it is also possible to create a custom lexer by implementing the `Lexer` abstract base class" [(1)](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html#syntax-highlighting), it doens't really explain how. I couldn't find any tutorial or really complete code example to illustrate how it works. Does anyone have any suggestion or example? I'm looking to creating a lexer from an application-specific derivative of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pygments to create your own lexer, for creating your own lexer you need to know regex https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

You can read this documentation link from pygments on creating your own lexer.
https://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/

heres a little example

```py
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments.token import Name

__all__ = ['CustomLexer']

class CustomLexer(RegexLexer):
     name = "sql type"
     tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r"\bSELECT\b", Name.Tag),
        ]}
```

and add this line into the file you want to import it in

```
lexer = pygments.lexers.load_lexer_from_file("name.py", lexername="CustomLexer")
```

Now in prompt_toolkit you also have the feature to edit the coloring of these docs link- https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/printing_text.html#pygments-token-text-tuples

```py
style = Style.from_dict({
    'pygments.name.tag': 'bg:#ffffff #000000',
})
```

Comment: thanks, getting somewhere! Now, based on your instructions and the `sql.py` lexer, I wrote [this](https://pastebin.com/PsZjEtrL). Unfortunately, it returns the following error: `AttributeError: type object 'VqlLexer' has no attribute 'lex_document'` Not sure I'm using thre right class. If, instead, I create my custom class based on prompt_toolkit's `Lexer` class, the error is: `TypeError: lex_document() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'`

Comment: @mrgou In the document it is written to keep the name of lexer CustomLexer and also make a different file for the lexer and a different file in which you are going to use prompt-toolkit

Comment: Then, if I move the class to a file named `lexer\vql_lexer.py`, rename the class CustomLexer and add `VqlLexer = load_lexer_from_file(r'lexer\vql_lexer.py', lexername="CustomLexer")` in my code, I still get `AttributeError: 'CustomLexer' object has no attribute 'lex_document'`...

Comment: @mrgou in which line do you get the error

Comment: That occurs at `query = session.prompt("VQL> ")`. Looks like prompt_toolkit requires a  [`lex_document`](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/reference.html?highlight=lex_document#prompt_toolkit.lexers.Lexer) function in the class, but there's no information as to how to use it. The [example](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/prompts/custom-lexer.py) in the GitHub repo doesn't really help either.

Comment: @mrgou even though its balantly off-topic to this question, in `PromptSession(lexer=PygmentsLexer(CustomLexer))` it needs to be this instead what you do

Comment: Thanks, that worked, provided that I actually keep the `CustomLexer` class in the main code rather than load it with `CustomLexer = load_lexer_from_file(r'lexer/vql_lexer.py', lexername="CustomLexer")`!